# How did biologists find out that bacterial plasmids were circular?

Tags: dna

I was always curious how it was determined that bacterial plasmids were circular, since there isn't an obvious way to find this out. I heard somewhere that there was a difference when gel electrophoresis was conducted. Could anyone give an explanation?

Comment: Where did you hear this? Having a reference would help.

Comment: i searched google that exact question and the first few pages talked about gel electrophoresis but sadly none of them gave a clear explanation